# Multiple timepickers in the same page bug

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I notice a strange behavior when there are multiple timepickers in the same page.
After switching between the two timepickers, eventually one of them isn't removed/hidden, and will persist till we refresh the page.

I thought it was a problem with my code but then i did a test with a simple bootstrap example i found on google.

Fiddle bug example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kW3G7/282/

The only code that is used is: 
`` `$('.timepicker').timepicker(); ``

Thanks in advance.

Edit:  i created a [issue](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/issues/239) in there github project

Edit 2: It seems that the timepicker stops calling the document onclick event(code above)

```
 $(document).on('mousedown.timepicker, touchend.timepicker', function (e) {
    // This condition was inspired by bootstrap-datepicker.
    // The element the timepicker is invoked on is the input but it has a sibling for addon/button.
    if (!(self.$element.parent().find(e.target).length ||
            self.$widget.is(e.target) ||
            self.$widget.find(e.target).length)) {
          self.hideWidget();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know if you use the jQuery datepickers you'll get the same reaction, what I would do is bind a click event to the text box and create the datepicker then and open it manually, then destroy it when you're done. This allows you to have multiple pickers and only ever have one open at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, for now, remove the "`touchend.timepicker`" from the "on" event trigger.

I don't think it is the proper/final solution but it seams to work.